# Flask API: How to clear database connection pool?

Tags: python, azure, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-restful

I have been wrestling with this issue for a few days now but can't seem to find any solution. I am trying to create a REST APIendpoint using Flask framework. The issue is that the API gives out correct results for some time and as some time passes it stops receiving any requests. I have no idea why it does that all of a sudden. My best guess is that its db connection pool doesn't get cleared up. As you can see in the below code i am closing the db connection properly still I am facing this issue. Please help!

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify
from flask_restful import Resource, Api
from flask_restful import reqparse
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from flask.ext.httpauth import HTTPBasicAuth
from flask.ext.cors import CORS

conn_string = "mssql+pyodbc://x"
e = create_engine(conn_string)

auth = HTTPBasicAuth()

@auth.get_password
def get_password(username):
    if username == 'x':
        return 'x'
    return None

app = Flask(__name__)
cors = CORS(app)
api = Api(app)

class Report(Resource):
    decorators = [auth.login_required]

    def get(self):
        parser = reqparse.RequestParser()
        parser.add_argument('start', type = str)
        parser.add_argument('end', type = str)
        args = parser.parse_args()

        conn = e.connect()

        stat = """
        select a, b from report where c < ? and d > ?
        """

        query = conn.execute(stat, [args['start'], args['end']])

        json_dict = []

        for i in query.cursor.fetchall():


            res = {'aa': i[0], 'bb':i[1]}
            json_dict.append(res)

        conn.close()
        return jsonify(results=json_dict)

api.add_resource(Report, '/report')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, are you running this on some sort of server / shared hosting or locally? If the former, does it work when run locally?

Comment: Yes I am running it on a server. No it doesnt work even when I run it locally. The API gives me results only for a day or so after which I have to restart the VM time and again.

Answer (score 0):

I build a quick test project based your code, connecting to Azure SQL database, querying a simple sentence `select * from (values (1), (2), (3), (4), (5)) numbers(number)`, running on local. And request this API 10 times per second via node.js. After a few hours test, it is still running well. Even I Disabled pooling using NullPool, which is shown on [SQLalchemy guide](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/pooling.html#switching-pool-implementations).

You can try to enlarge the [pool size](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/pooling.html#connection-pool-configuration) or [set Pool Recycle](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/pooling.html#setting-pool-recycle) when create SQLalchemy connection engine. If it is a db connection pool issue.

But per my test result, you can monitor you app for debugging.
For debugging flask apps running on local, you can leverage `logging` module, refer to http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/errorhandling/ for more information.